# How can I get the adress of a static mut from wasm (rust) to js?

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I have a rust-wasm project where I need to fill a buffer in webassembly before passing it to my js script and then display it with a canvas.

(Inspired by [this article](http://cliffle.com/blog/bare-metal-wasm/#making-some-pixels))

```
static mut BUFFER: [u32; WIDTH * HEIGHT] = [0; WIDTH * HEIGHT];
```

But a static mut in rust is unsafe, so I can’t declare it with `#[wasm_bindgen]`

How can I get the address of this static buffer in my js script?

#### EDIT :

I have seen this solution:

```
const { instance } = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(
          fetch("./demo.wasm")
        );

const buffer_address = instance.exports.BUFFER.value;
```

I don’t really understand what is happening in this code, and
I can’t use that because I use the wasm-pack buildtool: it creates for me the .js file corresponding to the wasm file, and I still can’t get the Buffer address.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your linked article uses `#[no_mangle]`, which makes `BUFFER` exported.

```
#[no_mangle]
static mut BUFFER: [u32; WIDTH * HEIGHT] = [0; WIDTH * HEIGHT];
```

The exported `BUFFER` can then be found on the instance, via `instance.exports.BUFFER.value;`.